# Donating by paypal is hard to find

Tags: system-installation

after trying to install and working with EOS on my Notebook i want to donate this realy great OS !!! It works so good and look so nice !!!
The only thing which doesn't work is the dual boot with windows10 but it don't mind because i do not further need windows any more (...and i am happy about it)
. The next thing was that i want to donate with paypal and that was difficult to find.
But at least i found it and you got 15 $ over paypal from me.
Sorry for this useless Tag but i have no idea to tell you in a other way...
Greetings
jochen

Comment: I would recommend submitting an issue on the elementary github page for the website. https://github.com/elementary/website/issues

Comment: I would love to pay for apps with PayPal. I avoid the paid apps due to the fact it can't be used. EDIT: sorry meant to add this as a comment not answer